# Better way to vectorize using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I am wondering if there is a better way to vectorize the following:

```
array = []
for ele in long_list:
    if condition:
        array.append(1)
vector = np.array(array)
```

Now this is essentially `np.ones(len(long_list))` except for that `if` condition.

Is there a better (vectorized) way of achieving the above?

Comment: What is `condition`? Is it testing against `ele` or something completely unrelated?

Comment: @Ffisegydd: Something like if ele.type == some_type

Comment: Is the condition always going to have the same value?

Comment: And does this mean that array is made up of 1, with length equal to however many trues?

Comment: @Joel: Yeah... that is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vector = np.fromiter((1 for ele in long_list if condition), dtype=int)
```

This should be faster than either:

```
vector = np.ones(len([x for x in long_list if conditon]))
```

or

```
vector = np.array( [1 for ele in long_list if condition(ele)] )
```

because it avoids building the filtered list, due to the fact that `(1 for ele in long_list if condition)` returns a generator not a list.

**EDIT**

I'm wondering if this isn't also a viable option:

```
vector = np.array( (1 for ele in long_list if condition(ele)) )
```

Comment: The first one doesnt work, it is asking for dtype.. vector = np.fromiter((1 for ele in [1,2,3]) ,dtype=int) works :) but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest in the question, you will get better performance if you evaluate the condition for the whole array at once (using vectorised NumPy operations) as opposed to checking each element individually in a loop.

Using vectorised operations to check a condition creates a Boolean array that you can compress and cast to produce your desired output of ones.

To illustrate this, here's an example checking whether elements of an array are less than 10:

```
>>> long_list = np.arange(500)
>>> b = long_list < 10
>>> np.compress(b, b).astype(int)
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

list comprehensions are faster than `for` loops.  I'm assuming the condition depends on `ele`.

```
array = [1 for ele in long_list if condition(ele)]

vector = np.array(array)
```

The other option would be to use a faster way of counting the cases where `condition(ele)` is `True`.  But the tricks I know that might do that generally depend on what that condition is.